# Update entities transactionally within a method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

For my application we have users voting on issues, with separate datastores for votes and issues. I want the up and down vote totals to be updated whnever a user votes (or changes their original vote), which I'm trying to do by updating the issue transactionally within a `Vote.Method`. To do this, I have the transaction:

```
@ndb.transactional
def GetToChange(vote):
    key = ndb.Key('Issue', vote.IID)
    issue = key.get()
    return issue
```

Then, within the `@Vote.Method` I call the transactional function:

```
@Vote.method(request_fields=('UID', 'IID', 'Vote'), name='vote.add', path ='addvote')
def AddVote(self, vote):
   vote.put()
   i = GetToChange(vote)
   if newvote.Vote == True:
      i.UpTotal += 1
   if newvote.Vote == False:
      i.DownTotal += 1
   i.put()
   return vote
```

However, this always gives me a 503 error, and in the logs I spot "NoneType i has  no attribute UpTotal", which suggests the entity isn't being retrieved. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: More details
This `@Vote.method`  takes a user ID (UID), Issue ID (the ID of an issue in the Issue datastore), and a boolean 'Vote' in the request. The vote is stored with vote.put(). I then call my transactional method to retrieve the issue using the IID from the request. 
I've added more to the code to show what I'm trying to do with the issue.

Comment: Additional note: I have also tried using the ndb Key property i.e
`IID = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Issue')`, but then passing the ID in the request (just pasting in the id from the Issue datastore into the IID field for the request in the API explorer) gives a 503 with a ProtocolBufferDecodeError "corrupted"

Comment: Not enough code provided.  In addition the error is telling you that no record was found in GetToChange, and why do you have a transactional decorator or GetToChange.  It should be vote method.  Lots of things look wrong here but we need more detail

Comment: You also don't have a put anywhere - hence the question for more code, and when/how have you created the entity in the first place?

Comment: To make it clear, the transactional is defined elsewhere in the code and then called within `@Vote.method`

Comment: But why are you calling a transactional get inside a transaction?

Comment: I was going on the example given in the NDB documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions

Comment: Yes but in the example a put was being performed.  In your case you are just doing a get inside GetToChange which does nothing for the bit of code you supplied. The transaction needs to be around AddVote, the get GetToChange will be part of the transaction then.

Comment: Aha, I follow, I have but the decorator where you mentioned and moved all the Issue operations inside a transactional; didn't mention that in my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, sorted! The problem was to do with the IID property I was using in the Vote model, which is why it was never able to retrieve the correct issue.

In the vote model, I changed the IID to `ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Issue)`. Trying to use the integer ID from the datastore didn't work though; as I commented above, this gave a `ProtocolBufferDecodeError "corrupted"`. However, passing the 64bit entitykey in the request works! So, now the API uses the entityKey helper property with Issues.